# Disable Youtube shortcuts or another workaround

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser, keyboard-shortcuts

I´ve been trying to get this to work for a while now and already searched for all the keywords i came up with.

I´m building a Chrome Extension, which opens a Modal on distracting Websites prompting the user to input what his intentions on this website are.

There might be more sites where this problem could occur, i only encountered youtube so far.

When the user inputs something youtube shortcuts are still active and the input field might lose focus. Let´s say someone inputs a 'f', youtube then fullscreens the video/ 'k' youtube start or stops the video.

Is there a way to disable youtube shortcuts ? Or another workaround, i´m not thinking of?

The Modal is inside a shadowRoot so it doesnt interfere with the styling of the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An event is dispatched in two phases:

1. capturing, where the event travels from `window` to the element via its DOM tree ancestors,
2. bubbling, where the event travels from the element to `window`, the default phase.

The solution is to register a listener in the first phase (capturing) on the first dispatch target (`window`), and stop the event so it never reaches the default second phase where the site is listening.

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', stopPropagation, true);

function stopPropagation(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

When your dialog is closed, restore the site's behavior:

```js
window.removeEventListener('keydown', stopPropagation, true);
```

P.S. On sites that already register a listener on `window` in the capturing phase you will have to attach your listener earlier by declaring the content script with ["run_at": "document_start"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time) and cancel the other listeners on `window` by adding `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`.